# How to create a sitemap for parent and separate folder structured websites?

Tags: seo, sitemap, analytics

We are looking at creating a parent and subsite folder structure, and 
we are not sure how to best create a sitemap for these separate installations
that all sit under a main site name.

Eg:

Parent: www.MyWebsite.com
Subsite/Folder: www.MyWebsite.com/Brand

The complication occurs when have the main website which is a Joomla CMS
installation:

www.MyWebsite.com

Which will have a shop made from Magento eCommerce as a separate folder

www.MyWebsite.com/Shop

A video sharing folder built from a Video Sharing PHP install:

www.MyWebsite.com/VideoSharer

and a blog built from Wordpress:

www.MyWebsite.com/News

If it were set up as subdomains (e.g. www.shop.Mywebstie.com) then submitting
a sitemap is relatively straight forward. Although it’s restrictions for SEO mean a 
folder structure will best optimise our SEO format for the site. Given though they are
all separate software installs & folders sitting under the main URL, how do we best
create a sitemap/sitemaps for the site given the different platforms in play?

Also will this same sitemap solution help with Google analytics?

Essentially how do we treat each folder as a separate site in google with regards to
Google Analytics for reporting, and sitemaps for SEO optimisation?

eg: Joomla, Magento eCommerce, Video PHP, Wordpress.

If anyone could point us in the right direction or share some help that would be 
greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: What have you tried? How many of these can create a sitemap for you? Can you control the sitemap file name in any of these?

Comment: Before we get the site up and running, we are trying to determine the best way of doing this. We know we can generate a separate sitemap for each site being Joomla, Magento, Video PHP and wordpress. The question is will Webmaster tools (google) be able to link to the four separate sitemaps in four separate folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sitemap for multiple folders under same domain :**

Sitemap is a list of urls for a web crawler to know the web structure and urls of your website to crawl.

There are various conventions followed by developers to create a sitemap. Like:

1) Single sitemap with all urls
2) Multiple sitemaps per directory or logical grouping of urls

But this does not make much of a difference as for crawler is concerned. It will pick those urls and crawl it.

Recommended approach:

1. Create a single file sitemap.xml
2. Add all root links + links for directory sitemaps inside it
3. Add directory sitemaps will have all links inside that directory +
   directory links if there are directory inside directory. This can be
   nested to any level
4. Advantage of this is a proper organization/management of sitemaps
   for you.

Even if your sub-directories are created by various tools ultimately your website is a set of links that crawler understands.

For easy management, you can have a individual product's sitemap created from its used platform/tool and link it in main sitemap.

**For google analytics:**

Under the same property in google analytics you can create different views based on your requirement.

Comment: Hi abhinsit, Thank you greatly for the time and effort you took to help us with this. We we're confused with the very best way to approach this, although your answer is simple thinking about it now. Do you have private details we can contact you on should we need any private consulting? Cheers,
Chris

Comment: We have a similar structure for one of our website and it rocks without any issues. If you feel the answer is appropriate please mark this as correct to help the community.